How to merge multiple (at least two) existing LlamaIndex VectorStoreIndex instances?
I'm working with LlamaIndex and have created two separate VectorStoreIndex instances, each from different documents. Now, I want to merge these two indexes into a single index. Here's my current setup:

I create and persist two separate indexes:

lyft_docs = SimpleDirectoryReader(input_files=["./data/10k/lyft_2021.pdf"]).load_data()
uber_docs = SimpleDirectoryReader(input_files=["./data/10k/uber_2021.pdf"]).load_data()

lyft_index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(lyft_docs)
uber_index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(uber_docs)

lyft_index.storage_context.persist(persist_dir="./storage/lyft")
uber_index.storage_context.persist(persist_dir="./storage/uber")


Later, I load these indexes:

storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(persist_dir="./storage/lyft")
lyft_index = load_index_from_storage(storage_context)

storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(persist_dir="./storage/uber")
uber_index = load_index_from_storage(storage_context)


Currently, I use separate QueryEngineTool instances for each index:

query_engine_tools = [
    QueryEngineTool(
        query_engine=lyft_index.as_query_engine(similarity_top_k=3),
        metadata=ToolMetadata(
            name="lyft_10k",
            description="Provides information about Lyft financials for year 2021."
        ),
    ),
    QueryEngineTool(
        query_engine=uber_index.as_query_engine(similarity_top_k=3),
        metadata=ToolMetadata(
            name="uber_10k",
            description="Provides information about Uber financials for year 2021."
        ),
    ),
]

My question is: How can I merge lyft_index and uber_index into a single index, and then use this merged index in a single QueryEngineTool? I want to maintain separate storage for each index but combine them for querying purposes. Is there a way to achieve this in LlamaIndex?
Ideally, I'd like to end up with something like:
merged_index = some_merging_function(lyft_index, uber_index)

query_engine_tools = [
    QueryEngineTool(
        query_engine=merged_index.as_query_engine(similarity_top_k=3),
        metadata=ToolMetadata(
            name="ride_sharing_10ks",
            description="Provides information on the company's financials for the year 2021 in response to user queries."
        ),
    ),
]


I have the same use-case and there seems to be a solution posted in the LlamaIndex forums.
https://github.com/run-llama/llama_index/discussions/8432
Pattern is:

Combine all indexes using GPTListIndex
Create a graph (ComposableGraph) from this combined index and save it to disk
Create an index while loading this graph from the disk

I am in the process of trying this out but this is the suggested solution.

I see. The reason why I want to combine all the indexes together is because I don't it's a proper way to create an index for each document.
